Doesn't using Contract Inheritance feature in Solidity increase gas cost, Why use it then?
So there's a feature called contract inheritance in Solidity which  allows us to break down our smart contract into smaller ones for better organization.
Wouldn't that end up costing more gas fees since now we got to deploy multiple contracts instead of just one? And if they do why we use it?
I tried looking this up on google and chatgpt where it does mention that it does increase the gas fees. But couldn't find an explanation on why that is.

It's a bit more complex than that. In Solidity, a contract can extend another, inheriting all the internal members and functions and can override them if they are virtual. This is like basic OOP, allowing for base contracts that are shared across different implementations. What you're talking about is more of a sharding configuration (like Diamonds) and is done through calls, delegatecalls and public library functions (which behave like delegatecalls). Any call is something like 700some gas depending on variables.
